# How to set custom variable on VueJS using vue analytics component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, analytics, google-analytics-api

I need to set custom variable with vue analytics:

```
_gaq.push(["_setCustomVar", 1, "MyPage", "NewVersion", 1]);
```

But it allows only to trackEvent:

```
this.$ga.event(eventCategory, eventAction, eventLabel, eventValue)
```

Can anyone help me?